# split a symbol hash into string arrays of keys and values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, key-value

Is there any way to split a symbol hash into string arrays of keys and values ?

for example:

```
hash = {:key1 => 'val1',:key2 => 'val2'}
```

Should be:

```
keys = ['key1', 'key2']
values = ['val1','val2']
```

I know I can do it by this way:

```
keys = hash.keys.map { |key| key.to_s }
values = hash.values.map { |val| val.to_s }
```

But I would like to do it in just one loop.

Comment: Can you explain a bit further?  At them moment what you are asking for is confusing.  For example you talk about symbol hash, but define it as `array = [:key1 => val1,:key2 => val2]` which isn't valid ruby syntax.   Also array's don't have key or values methods.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake... See updated question.

Comment: OK, I can't see a simple way to do this in one command.  What is the motivation?  If it's really important to do in one command I think you're gonna need to define a custom method. Could you not use `.to_a`?

Answer (score 0):

I found this question because I was also looking for a way to do this. This is what I came up with:

```
hash.map { |k,v| [k.to_s, v.to_s] }.transpose
```

which you can use like so:

```
hash = { :k1 => "v1", :k2 => "v2", :k3 => "v3" }
keys, values = hash.map { |k,v| [k.to_s, v.to_s] }.transpose
# keys == ["k1", "k2", "k3"]
# values == ["v1", "v2", "v3"]
```

Comment: Thanks. It would be better to do: `keys, values = hash.stringify_keys.to_a.transpose`

Comment: Yes, that is much nicer!